# can't acces to library class namespace asp.net from another namespace

Tags: asp.net, datamodel

I have one ASP.NET solution with two library classes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5jMF.jpg)

I have referenced from `WebElQuijote` to `Datamodel` but I can't access to folders' `Datamodel` in my controllers.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you can't access folders of your project Datamodel or do you mean you can't access its namespace as stated in the title of your question?

Because you are using two different projects in one solution, the best you could do is creating Datamodel as a DLL, depending on what you want to achieve. After that you can just reference this DLL in your web project and use the functions of it.